# LibGDX game crashes with "java platform se binary stopped working"

Tags: java, debugging, android-ndk, crash, libgdx

Im having this really weird problem where my LibGDX game, suddently, after a few minutes playing, crashes with no Exceptions thrown, it just freezes and crashes, and I have to force the process down.

I have no idea how to debug this kind if error and google searches are not helping with this particular case.

I tried to run it on android to see if Logcat would say something about it, and i got this:

[image]

Any idea what could make the game crash like this, with no errors or exceptions? Or any way of fetching better logs or something to help narrow the problem down?

P.S.: The first crashing happened on Desktop, and it still happens on Desktop, I only ran it on android to get more logs, but it is not an "android only" problem, just clarifying.

Comment: Try using a heap analyzer (https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html).  You probably have a memory leak, and then there is probably some code path in the native libraries that isn't prepared for an allocation failure.

Answer (score 2):

could do a quick test, modifying the manifest:

```
 <application        
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:vmSafeMode="true"       
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
```

but perhaps not fix your error, you can take a look at this threads -->

1. [Android libc.so crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369301/android-libc-so-crash)
2. [Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x636f7d89 (code=1). How can it be tracked down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked)

maybe you need to use `ndk-stack`, hope to help you in some way to fix it,
It is an error of memory management, the native side, the error does not occur in the Java code does not display a stack with many details, but can also look if when you display the logcat, the error may look if you see something that can you suggest where the error might be occurring

Answer (score -1):

Well I had the same problem.
I Know this Question was asked 3 years ago but, but if any one has a problem like this it might help.
 I was making a game whit LibGDX, and while  running the Game it crash and the
and after the force Stop it said `"Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working"`,
After two hours of looking to see what could it be, and re writhing the code I notice that in one for loop I Wrote in the increment part **=+** and not **+=**,  like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < something; i =+ somethingElse)
```

After I change it,

```
for (int i = 0; i < something; i += somethingElse)
```

I did not have that error any more.

MY suggestion,if you have this error check your loops.